# Why the value of a function is 1?

Tags: c++

I just learn C++ and i don't understand what is the used of return even with the help of google, here is a code that returns the value 9 to returnvalue but the output of the code below is 1 why is this so won't 9 = returnvalue? If not then can i return any value back to my function will that affect anything?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int returnvalue(){
    return 9;}
int main(){
    cout<<returnvalue;}
```

Comment: Try this: `cout<<returnvalue();` with the `()` on the end, which means "call this function, with no arguments".

Comment: @Eljay It works thankyou so much

Comment: @SirGuy im sorry

Comment: @user93228 What about accepting the duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're feeding `std::cout` a funtion pointer to `returnvalue` instead of calling it, to call it add `()`:

```
cout<<returnvalue();
```